# Testing for Schmidt groups with GAP

Tags: gap

I've written the following simple code to test (with GAP) whether a
finite group $G$ is a Schmidt group, that is, a group which is not nilpotent but each of its proper subgroups is.

```
IsSchmidtGroup := function(G) 
local M,i; i:=0;;
if Length(Factors(Order(G))) = 1 then 
    return false;
elif Length(Factors(Order(G))) > 2 then 
    return false;
elif IsNilpotentGroup(G) then 
    return false;
else   
    for M in ConjugacyClassesMaximalSubgroups(G) do
        if IsNilpotentGroup(M) then 
            i:=i+1; 
        fi;
    od;
    if Length(ConjugacyClassesMaximalSubgroups(G)) = i then 
        return true;
    else 
        return false;
    fi;
fi;
end;
```

The purpose of the first if is to discard $p$-groups. It is known that a Schmidt group has exactly two prime divisors, so the second if takes care of that. The third one asks if the group is nilpotent, despite having exactly two prime divisors for its order. The final part actually tests if each maximal subgroup of $G$ is nilpotent (clearly, this is equivalent to $G$ being a Schmidt group).

BUT: I'm doing something wrong here, since the I've asked for IsSchmidtGroup(S), S being the symmetric group of order 6, and I get an error.

Could anyone offer advice?

---

I have a further, unrelated, question. I'm thinking I should ask it here, because it is quite specific and I don't believe anyone would benefit in any way from reading it (but I'm happy to ask it separately). I define the following function in GAP, which takes a group $G$ and returns the probability that two subgroups of $G$ permute:

```
spd := function(G)
local allsubs, subreps, count, H, K;
subreps := Flat(List(ConjugacyClassesSubgroups(G),Representative));
allsubs := Flat(List(ConjugacyClassesSubgroups(G),Elements));
count:=0;
for H in subreps do;
for K in allsubs do;
if ArePermutableSubgroups(H,K) then
count := count+Index(G,Normalizer(G,H));
fi; 
od; 
od;
return Float(count/(Size(allsubs)^2));
end;
```

Ok, but now I want to define a new function, call it `spd_sect`, which assigns to each group $G$ the minimum of $\mathrm{spd}(S)$ as $S$ runs
over all sections of $G$ (and then look at their difference in certain cases). I was thinking something along the lines of:

```
spd_sect := function(G)
local subreps, s, H, K; s:=1.0;;
subreps := Flat(List(ConjugacyClassesSubgroups(G),Representative));
for H in subreps do;
for K in NormalSubgroups(H) do;
if spd(FactorGroup(H,K)) < s then s:=spd(FactorGroup(H,K)); fi;                   
od;
od;
return s;
end;
```

Does this look ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ConjugacyClassesMAximalSubgroups` returns classes of subgroups, not the actual subgroups. So you should replace the `for' loop by

```
for M in List(ConjugacyClassesMaximalSubgroups(G),Representative) do
```

or

```
for M in MaximalSubgroupClassReps(G) do
```

Also (simplifying the logic), instead of counting, your loop could simply use

```
if not IsNilpotentGroup(M) then return false;fi;
```

and at the end of the loop `return true;`